# Xamarin RotateTo breaks binding

Tags: c#, mobile, xamarin, data-binding

I'm getting started using Xamarin, but I can't seem to get data bindings hooked down. Essentially I have a button that's RotationProperty is set to a binding of a sliders ValueProperty, but the button also has a click event which rotates it by 90 degrees. The binding works fine and so does the click event but when I click the button to rotate it seems to break the binding on the buttons RotationProperty. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? (I'm going to guess the latter).

### Code Behind File:

```
    Binding binding = new Binding();
    public Anim()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        binding.Source = sldr0;
        binding.Path = "Value";
        btn0.SetBinding(RotationProperty, binding);
    }
    private void OnBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btn0.RemoveBinding(RotationProperty);
        var btn = (Button)sender;
        var change = btn.Rotation + 90;
        if (change > 360)
        {
            change = change - 360;
        }
        sldr0.Value = change;
        btn.RotateTo(change, 250U, Easing.SpringOut);
        btn0.SetBinding(RotationProperty, binding);
    }
```

### XAML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.Views.Anim">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>     
      <Button x:Name="btn0"
              Grid.Row="0"
              Text="Button"
              VerticalOptions="Center"
              HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              Clicked="OnBtnClick"/>
      <Slider x:Name="sldr0"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Value="0"
              Minimum="0"
              Maximum="360"
              VerticalOptions="Center"
              HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Slider>
      <Label Grid.Row="1"
             Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference btn0}, Path=Rotation}>
      </Label>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Why are you removing the binding? You could just rotate the button, wait for the animation to complete and update the slider value.

Comment: @Krumelur I added that to try to fix the issue, and I tried this before it didn't work